# How user can se own product in EasyAdmin but admin can se all products?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I use EasyAdmin 3 in my Symfony project, the problem I have with easyAdmin is that, I have two roles, role admin and role artist.
I found how it works for each one to se their own  products which published but i want admin to see all of everyone's products,
I mean that artists must see their own products and admin see everyone's products in easyadmin?

I will be thankfull if someone give a hand

```html
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;


use App\Entity\Product;

use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;


use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\SearchDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\SlugField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\MoneyField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IntegerField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextEditorField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FieldCollection;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FilterCollection;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class ProductCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Product::class;
    }

    public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
    {
        $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $qb = parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
        $qb->where('entity.user = :id');
        $qb->setParameter('id', $user);

        return $qb;
    }
```

Thank you Hamid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending of the user role you'll have to add or not the `where` condition on user id.
So if the user is admin, don't add the `where` condition. Else, add the `where` condition.

To test the user role, you can call `$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')`

It would be something like this :

```
public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    $user = $this->getUser()->getId();
    $qb = parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
    if (!$this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
       $qb->where('entity.user = :id');
       $qb->setParameter('id', $this->getUser()->getId());
    }
    return $qb;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome, if you can just give me a little thumbs up on my answer it would make my day :)